# How to remove the hidden character ^@ on linux?

Tags: linux, sed, replace, character, hidden

After viewing a file with `cat -A`, I saw that a bunch of lines in my text file start with `^@`. This seems to be a hidden character, as it doesn't show up when just using `cat` to view the file.

How can I replace this character so that is just reads as a visible `@` symbol?

To illustrate:

```
$ cat tmp
NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:16713:1056 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG
NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:19070:1057 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG
NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:11485:1057 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG

$ cat -A tmp
^@NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:16713:1056 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG$
^@NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:19070:1057 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG$
^@NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:11485:1057 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG$
```

What I want to have in the end is this:

```
$ cat tmp
@NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:16713:1056 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG
@NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:19070:1057 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG
@NB501485:33:HLLFTBGX2:1:11101:11485:1057 1:N:0:CACGCCGGCCGG
```

I tried using `Ctrl+V+@` to type the hidden character in a `sed` replacement query but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: those are [Null characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)... you can use `sed 's/\x0/@/' tmp` but why do you want to replace them?

Comment: `^@` is also known as NUL, or `'\0'`.  Control-A is character code 1; letter A has (ASCII) code 65.  The character code `@` has ASCII code 64; Control-@ is character code 0.  Normally, NUL bytes don't appear in text files; they confuse things.  For example, if the program treats the input as a string, the NUL terminates the string.  You might do best with `tr '\0' '@' < tmp > tmp.2`.

Comment: Great, thank you this worked!